# Problemas con servidor local xampp

Tags: laravel, apache, xampp

Estoy trabajando en laravel tengo un problema con mi servidor local de xampp apache no me esta corriendo mi base de datos y no puedo visualizar mis datos solo usando el comando php artisan server ahi si me funciona correctamente mas que todo quisiera poder usarlo solo con el apache y no con con el php artisan server no se si es problema de la version o cual podria ser el problema

**este es mi xampp**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**y aqui no me esta traendo los datos de mi base**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**pero si apago el apache y corro el comando php artisan server si me funciona todo correctamente no entiendo por que al solo usar el apache de xampp no me funciona**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

lo intente de esta forma pero ala hora de colocar el puerto 80 asi como lo tengo me bloquea el puerto y no me inicia mi apache asi es como debe estar correctamente el directorio como ingreso en la web

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

de esta forma lo deje y ese es el problema que me tira no tengo permisos me indica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

En tu archivo `httpd-vhosts.conf` normalmente ubicado en `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra` debiste haber declarado tu `VirtualHost`, agrega esta sección:

```
<Directory /Directorio/De/Tu/Proyecto/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Donde `/Directorio/De/Tu/Proyecto/` debe ser reemplazado por la ruta completa de tu proyecto y luego debes acceder a la carpeta `public`, por eso la ruta completa dice `public` al final

Si eso no funciona entonces intenta con esto

```
<Directory  "/Directorio/De/Tu/Proyecto/public">
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Edición:**

La sección anterior se debe incluir adentro de la declaración de `VirtualHost`, te dejo un ejemplo completo

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Directorio/De/Tu/Proyecto/public"
    ServerName TuServerName
    ServerAlias www.TuServerAlias.dev.com
    ErrorLog "logs/TuServerAlias.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/TuServerAlias.com-access.log" common
    <Directory  "/Directorio/De/Tu/Proyecto/public">
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Al declararlo así podrás también utilizar `www.TuServerAlias.dev.com` como URL en tu navegador para acceder a tu página.

Las líneas de `ErrorLog` y `CustomLog` son para que guardes un registro de errores y sea más fácil analizarlos

Comment: He intentado hacerlo de esta forma    pero aun no me funciona se me bloquea el puerto y no el apache me deja de funcionar 
<Directory  "localhost:80/salesSystem/public/">
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: ahi deje en el comentario la forma en que lo hice

Comment: @jveliz, la implementación completa como la hiciste está un poco mal, debes incluir la parte que te comenté adentro de tu declaración de VirtualHost, edité mi respuesta con un ejemplo completo

Comment: lo he intentado de esa forma pero ahora me tira el error que no tengo permiso para acceder a ese sitio (You don't have permission to access this resource) edite  una respuesta nueva como lo hice  y ala par lo que me tira

Comment: deje una respuesta nueva como lo hice y lo que me tira ahora

Comment: No estás haciendo lo que puse en la respuesta....... revisa todos los campos que te puse que deben ser sustituidos con TUS datos y además debe ser la ruta COMPLETA, tal como dice la respuesta `C:/.........`

Comment: Otra cosa, no agregues respuestas, si necesitas incluir más datos edita tu pregunta y agrega la información ahí, las respuestas  que pusiste probablemente serán cerradas ya que son información adicional de tu pregunta

Comment: lo hice de esta forma pero ahora me tira el error The requested URL was not found on this server. ahi edite la respuesta

Comment: ¿Y qué url estás usando?

Comment: ahi edite la respuesta como lo realice ingreso al navegador con localhost:80/salesSystem

Comment: Copio y pego mi comentario anterior porque es lo mismo... [No estás haciendo lo que puse en la respuesta....... revisa todos los campos que te puse que deben ser sustituidos con TUS datos y además debe ser la ruta COMPLETA, tal como dice la respuesta `C:/.........`] Por favor lee cuidadosamente lo que estas escribiendo en tu VirtualHost